# Converting daily data to weekly data using R

Tags: r, data.table, tidyquant

I have the daily data of two stocks (Apple and Google)

```
library(tidyquant)
dt = tidyquant::tq_get(c("AAPL", "GOOG")) %>%
  arrange(symbol, date)
```

I am trying to convert this data from daily to weekly using the following code

```
result = dt %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  tidyquant::tq_transmute(mutate_fun = to.weekly) %>% data.table
result[symbol == "AAPL" & date == "2017-02-03"]
```

Somehow, the result is wrong.
As an example, the weekly data for `AAPL` on `2017-02-03` is coming as follows using the above code-

```
   symbol       date    open    high   low close   volume 
1:   AAPL 2017-02-03 32.0775 32.2975 32.04 32.27 98029200
```

However, the correct result should be -

```
   symbol       date     open     high      low  close   volume 
1:   AAPL 2017-02-03  30.2325  32.6225  30.1550  32.2700 999124986
```

Can someone help me here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing: a bug, see [github issue 148](https://github.com/business-science/tidyquant/issues/148).

A possible workaround, using tidyr and timetk and purrr. Using timetk to get the data into xts format, transform data into weekly and turn back into a data.frame format. Including `nest` and `unnest` from tidyr and `map` from purrr. data.table is not needed but prints the data a lot better than tibbles.

```
library(tidyr)
library(timetk)
# library(purrr)

result <- dt %>% 
  group_by(symbol) %>% 
  nest() %>%   
  mutate(data = purrr::map(data, function(x) x %>% 
                             select(date, Open = open, High = high, Low = low, Close = close) %>% 
                             tk_xts(x, select = c(Open, High, Low, Close), date_var = date) %>% 
                             to.weekly %>% 
                             tk_tbl)) %>% 
  unnest(data) %>% 
  rename_with( ~ tolower(gsub("..", "", .x, fixed = T))) %>% 
  rename(date = index)

result %>% 
  data.table %>% 
  filter(date == "2017-02-03")

   symbol       date     open     high     low  close
1:   AAPL 2017-02-03  30.2325  32.6225  30.155  32.27
2:   GOOG 2017-02-03 814.6600 815.8400 790.520 801.49
```

Comment: I ended up using ```lapply``` and ```to.weekly``` to make it faster. Library ```timetk``` made it really easy to convert data.table to xts without much hassle.  Thanks.